# Understanding Noise Generator Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise

I am looking at Figure 13.119 in The Art of Electronics, which shows a psuedo random bit sequence generator using shift registers. I understand how this functions. It then takes taps off of the shift registers, using various resistor values to feed into an op amp circuit which then outputs the noise... The book mentions that the values are derived from sin(x) / x [I think?].

What I am asking is, how and why the resistor values used were chosen? And why this works with the op amp configuration shown?

Here is the figure for reference:

[image: figure 13.119]

Comment: Take the reciprocal of each resistor to get its conductance, that's the value of the FIR tap it creates. Positive taps for the middle two S/Rs, negative taps for the outer two, because that's the sign of the diff-amp U2 input they go to.

Answer (score 2):

Horowitz & Hill, under that figure, specify:

> In this case we have used a \$sin(\pi x) /  x\$ weighted sum over 32
>   successive values of the sequence.

Presumably, the resistance values were chosen for this weighting scheme.

Answer (score 1):

It is to have the output "samples" correctly interpolated to bandwidth limited analog impulses, rather than having a "zero order hold" type of DAC output which is a stair case waveform that has harmonics of the actual signal.

Basically it does the same as a digital FIR filter, so that the analog output filter can be simpler and cheaper. So think of it like an oversampling DAC built from discrete components.

Resistor values are indeed selected based on sin(x)/x coefficients, positive coefficents go to non-invering input and negative coefficients go to inverting input of the output buffer amplifier.